# findViewById() returns null for some custom views in single layout application while it works fine for others

Tags: android, android-layout

Link to my layout view:

[image: layout view]

Added logcat in answer sections since it was too much for body maybe I should have just posted errors from logcat...

All the knob widgets I imported from this project:
https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android

show up in my single layout view, but when ran on my phone findViewById() returns null for the keyboard widget I imported. I'm not sure why.
The constructor calls super(context,attrs) for all widgets and my content view is set.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Our base Synthesizer model
    //TODO: DSP AND MIDI NOTE ON NOTE OFF
    synthesizerModel = new SynthesizerModel();


    thread = new SynthesizerAudioOutputThread();

    thread.setSynthesizerModel(synthesizerModel);

    //The widget returning null
    keyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.kv);
    //the other widget returning null
    scrollStripView = (ScrollStripView) findViewById(R.id.ssv);

    //KNOBS//

    knobViews = new KnobView[20];

    knobViews[0] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_0_0);
    knobViews[1] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_0_1);
    knobViews[2] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_0_2);
    knobViews[3] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_0_3);

    knobViews[4] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_1_0);
    knobViews[5] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_1_1);
    knobViews[6] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_1_2);
    knobViews[7] = (KnobView) findViewById(R.id.mod_1_3);
    ///Other code all the KnobViews are found
```

The Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/frequency"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/_0"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/_1"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/_2"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/_3"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/master"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="3"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:rowCount="4"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2">

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_0_0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_1_0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_2_0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_3_0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_0_1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_1_1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_2_1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_3_1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_0_2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_1_2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_2_2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_3_2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="3" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_0_3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_1_3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_2_3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="2" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/mod_3_3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="3" />

        </GridLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2">

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/out_0" />
            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/out_1" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/out_2" />

            <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.knob.KnobView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/out_3" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>

    <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.keyboard.ScrollStripView
        android:id="@+id/ssv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scrollstripheight"/>

    <com.csun_comp380_15884.group3.synthesizerapp.keyboard.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/kv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:octaves="2"
        app:first_octave="4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You made sure all the id's you are using are correct? (kv, ssv, mod_0_0 etc.)

Comment: Where does your findViewById hit the nullPointerException? The exact point of origin of your error.

Comment: Yes all my ids are correct. I don't call any other functions to hit a null pointer exception I just know that they return null to their respective variables after stepping through the program they won't show up on my UI when running the app.

Comment: Post your layout XML.

Comment: posted layout XML I'm sure its correct it must have to do with something else specific to the view, it works fine in the original project I imported the keyboard widget from just not in my project this is a link to the activity for the original project: https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/levien/synthesizer/android/ui/PianoActivity2.java

Comment: XML looks fine. Could you post full LogCat?

Comment: This is for school so my project is here if you want to import it to your android studio or eclipse: https://github.com/marvinharcsun/SynthesizerAppMarvinsClone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
```

I fixed it guys thank you so much for the help I realized my linear layout was also returning NULL so I delete my old XML and copy pasted a new one changing this line thanks! Just deleting the old layout worked and copy pasting worked I don't know why, but I'm happy!